# JSESSIONID Cookie Conflict

Tags: java, tomcat, cookies, session-cookies, tomcat6

Multiple tomcat6 server in single Server with same application on different ports.

http://IPAddress:8080/manTest

http://IPAddress:8089/manLive

http://IPAddress:8056/manProduction

While accessing this from IE9 , IE11 on same tabs, one instance will be working , all other instances will be redirected to login page.

I read in one article its because of JSESSIONID cookie conflict.

I have added the argument in CATALINA_OPTS

-Dorg.apache.catalina.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME=TOMCAT8293JSESSIONID

-Dorg.apache.catalina.SESSION_PARAMETER_NAME=tomcat8293jsessionid

But I still face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I remember one of the project I worked on, where we appended tomcat id and server id to JsessionId.  This was done in server.xml
note: we didn't change the cookie name but the value of the cookie was suffixed with tomcatid and serverid  e.g.   Jsessionid=xxxxxxxxt02d03

Comment: Thanks ! server.xml of tomcat ? Is it Tomcat 6 or Tomcat7 ?